# Retrieving data from JSON array (PHP) and populating textboxes

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to pull the data gathered from the MySQL query referenced below and populate the corresponding textboxes with that data:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$server = "••••";
$username = "••••";
$password = "••••";
$database = "••••";

$username_pull = $_POST['a_username'];

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$sql = "SELECT uname, pword, fullname, phone_num, email_add, car_details FROM app_login WHERE uname = '$username_pull'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $records[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($con);

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . json_encode($records);

?>
```

If I insert in $username_pull = "admin", I get the following json info, so I know it works:

```
[{"uname":"admin","pword":"password","fullname":"John Smith","phone_num":"123-456-7890","email_add":"john@website.com","car_details":"2013 Black Cadillac ATS"}]
```

Here's my json callback function:

```
function fillTheGap() 
{
    var f_uname = $("#a_username").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "login2.php",
        data: f_uname,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "jsoncallback",
        success: function(data) 
        {
                $("#a_phonenum").val(data.phone_num);
            $("#a_fullname").val(data.fullname);
            $("#a_email").val(data.email_add);
            $("#a_cardetails").val(data.car_details);
            },});
}
```

Here's the form that initiates the data pulling:

```
    <form name="check_user" method="" action="post">
        Your Username: 
        <input id="a_username" name="a_username" type="text" onBlur="fillTheGap()">
        Your Full Name: 
        <input id="a_fullname" name="a_fullname" type="text">
        Your Phone Num:
        <input id="a_phonenum" name="a_phonenum" type="text">
        <input name="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How do I make it to where it populates the textboxes with its corresponding ID name?

I greatly appreciate everyone's help in advance!

Comment: "same ID" how exactly, you can only use an ID once, it's unique? Also, your database functions are wide open to XSS attacks!

Comment: You're right. I'll take the necessary precautions to avoid those problems. And you're right about the ID's. I meant to try doing this with classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
data = {"uname":"admin","pword":"password","fullname":"John Smith","phone_num":"123-456-7890","email_add":"john@website.com","car_details":"2013 Black Cadillac ATS"}

$.each(data, function(key, value){
       $("#a_"+key).val(value);
});
```

So your function should be something like:

```
function fillTheGap() 
{
    var f_uname = $("#a_username").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "login2.php",
        data: f_uname,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "jsoncallback",
        success: function(data) 
        {
              $.each(data, function(key, value){
                 $("#a_"+key).val(value);
              });
        }
    });
}
```

Also you can try it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nhKks/